# Access nested property of an object

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have to access property on object:

```
var jsonobj= {
    "first": {
        "second": 120
    }
}
```

How to check if `second` is available or not? `jsonobj.hasOwnProperty()` returns `false` if we check here.

If I want to change the value of `second` from 120 to 100, how can I achieve it?
Can I get a generalized solution, so that it works for any number of hierarchies?

**Edit**:
What if I don't know the name of the property?

Comment: `jsonobj.first.second = 100;` will do it. As to a generalised solution, how do you picture that working for duplicate property names? The object could have several properties that all reference other objects that each have their own `second` property, or the same property name could be used at several levels such that `obj.first.second.second.second` is not the same as `obj.first.second` - so which would you return? Also, this is _not_ JSON, it's an object (or nested objects) - [there's no such thing as a JSON object](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/).

Comment: @nnnnnn : thanx for ur link. I just understood the difference between json and object literal! :)

Comment: Please note that the problem has **nothing** to do with JSON at all. It seems you are confusing JavaScript object literals (constructs of the JavaScript language syntax) with JSON (a language-independent data-exchange format, like XML or CSV). I will edit your question accordingly. See also: [There is no such thing as a "JSON object"](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to check the existence of [the unique path to] a nested property [key], this function may help:

```
function keyPathExists(obj,keypath){
  var keys = keypath.split('.'), key, trace = obj;
  while (key = keys.shift()){
    if (!trace[key]){
      return null
    };
    trace = trace[key];
  }
  return true;
}

//usages
var abcd = {a:{b:{c:{d:1}}}};
keyPathExists(abcd,'a.b.c.d'); //=> 1
keyPathExists(abcd,'a.b.c.d.e'); //=> null
if (keyPathExists(abcd,'a.b.c.d')){
 abcd.a.b.c.d = 2;
}
```

Please read [@nnnnnn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/615754/nnnnnn)s comment, especially the provided [link](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/) within it carefully.

Answer (score 0):

Use `typeof`:

```
if(typeof jsonobj.first == 'undefined'){
    jsonobj.first = {};
}
if(typeof jsonobj.first.second == 'undefined'){
    jsonobj.first.second = {};
}    
jsonobj.first.second = 100;
```

Comment: What if `first` isn't defined?

Comment: same, check for undefined, updated code

Answer (score 0):

To change the value, you can use the "dot" notation - so try: `jsonobj.first.second = 100`

Answer (score 0):

```
var jsonobj= {
              "first": {
                           "second": 120
                        }
           }

alert(jsonobj.first.second);

jsonobj.first.second = 100

alert(jsonobj.first.second);​
```

Comment: What if i dont know the structure of the json object?

Comment: how would you change a property if you don't know the structure?... What if there is another property with the same name somewhere else in the object tree