# Accessing values of a JSON-encoded object

Tags: javascript, json, jquery

I am sending a JSON encoded array from my controller to my view page. I am doing this on my view page to get the data:

```
 function () {
     $.get('http://localhost/Location/loc', function(data){
         alert(data[0].message);
     });
 }
```

The data is like this

```
 {"message":"hello!"}
```

I am alerting the value of message but my alert giving me `undefined`. My question is     how can I access values of JSON array?

I am new to JSON so I don't know much about JSON.

Comment: try `alert(data.message);`

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to parse JSON in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4935632/how-to-parse-json-in-javascript)

Comment: possible duplicate of [access property of json object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12346203/access-property-of-json-object)

Comment: @srain didnt work ... i am getting undefined

Comment: simply examine your json object in debugger. If you are using chrome, hit f12 to open it, go to source and set a breakpoint on that line with your alert. Then look into data

Comment: @mynameisbutt, ok, I posted an answer, hope that would work for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing your function to:

```
function () {
     $.get('http://localhost/Location/loc', function(data){
         alert(data.message);
     }, 'json');
}
```

This is because jQuery probably doesn't know that the response data is JSON, so it's assuming that it's plaintext. You can explicitly specify it in `$.get` as the last parameter as in the revised code, or configure your server to send the response with the HTTP Content-Type header of `application/json`.

I'm assuming this because `message` is not a property of a String and that's why you're getting undefined.

Alternatively, you may use [`$.getJSON`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/):

```
function () {
     $.getJSON('http://localhost/Location/loc', function(data){
         alert(data.message);
     });
}
```

Also note that I have changed the alert to `data.message`. See Knaģis' answer for explanation.

Answer (score 1):

You data contains a single object, not an array.

In your case use `alert(data.message);` instead.

An array is defined using `[]` brackets, for example `[{message:"hello"}, {message:"world"}]` is an array with two objects in it.

Comment: @mynameisbutt - did you use Fiddler or another tool to see what exactly is returned from the server?

Answer (score 0):

OK, if this does not work:

```
function () {
     $.get('http://localhost/Location/loc', function(data){
         alert(data.message);
     });
}
```

try this:

```
function () {
     $.get('http://localhost/Location/loc', function(data){
         alert(data.message);
     }, 'json');
}
```

Comment: well thankyou ... it worked for me .. but as rink posted it first so i mark his answer . thankyou very much